# Nrwl Nx generates service instead of lib?

Tags: angular-cli, nrwl

In the root of my Nx workspace, when I run the command `ng g lib my-lib` it generates a **service** called `MyLibService` in a `myLib/src/libs` folder in the **root of my workspace**.  I would expect it to create a new **lib** inside the **libs** folder (`libs/my-lib/src`). (It used to do this before I upgraded to v6.)

- Angular 6.1.0
- NRWL Nx 6.1.1
- Angular CLI 6.1.0-rc.0 (pinned to that to avoid https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/640)

Also, **nothing** is added to my `angular.json` file after the service is created.

So there's at least three things going wrong:

1. The path where the artifact is generated is wrong.
2. It's generating a `service` instead of a `lib`
3. Nothing being recorded in `angular.json`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**Update #1**

I created a new test workspace, added an app, and added a lib to that using the same command as above.  Everything worked as expected, so I think that means my environment (packages, etc) is correct.  I compared the angular.json files for the dummy workspace and my real workspace and found that my real workspace was missing one entry that seemed relevant: `"defaultCollection": "@nrwl/schematics"`.

I added that entry and now when I try to create a lib, it sits there for 10-15 seconds and then reports:

```
ERROR! test2/karma.conf.js does not exist..
ERROR! test2/ng-package.json does not exist..
ERROR! test2/ng-package.prod.json does not exist..
ERROR! test2/package.json does not exist..
ERROR! test2/tsconfig.lib.json does not exist..
ERROR! test2/tsconfig.spec.json does not exist..
ERROR! test2/tslint.json does not exist..
ERROR! test2/src/test.ts does not exist..
ERROR! test2/src/index.ts does not exist..
ERROR! test2/src/lib/test2.component.ts does not exist..
ERROR! test2/src/lib/test2.module.ts does not exist..
ERROR! libs/test2/src/lib/test2.module.ts does not exist..
ERROR! libs/test2/src/index.ts does not exist..
ERROR! libs/test2/tsconfig.lib.json does not exist..
ERROR! libs/test2/tsconfig.spec.json does not exist..
ERROR! libs/test2/tslint.json does not exist..
ERROR! libs/test2/karma.conf.js does not exist..
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

'test2' was the name of the lib I tried to create

Now, nothing is created anywhere, and my angular.json is not modified.

I'm continuing to dig into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  I reset all of the package versions in my real workspace `package.json` to the version from the `package.json` that worked (generally Angular 6.0.1).  Cleared out my `node_modules` folder and ran yarn.  Everything works now.

On an unrelated issue on the Nrwl/Nx GitHub repo, Victor Savkin commented that Angular 6.1 will not be supported until Nx 6.2.

Lesson learned: Don't always update to the latest version of things...wait a bit and stay a rev or two behind, unless you have a specific reason to upgrade!